# Want to rank players for each session based on number of wins, games, and then points

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, array-formulas

I want to automatically decide who's 1st, 2nd, 3rd, and 4th for each session. I want it to be decided based on the number of match wins first, then game wins if matches are equal, and then points if games are equal. If everything is equal, then have 2 players as the same position and the next one skipped (1st, 2nd, 2nd, and 4th). The highlighted cells are where I want to calculate this. Can someone please help me with this?

Sample file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ry3BAqXF4Di5lHGlY_roDyzQz7FmTaP1XvhO6Psm4sU/edit#gid=0

I have looked online for something, but have been unsuccessful in finding a formula for 3 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's an exact formula for this. Obviously SORT or SORTN would correctly sort them, but not return ranking with equals. What I thought of is to MAP the ranking of each column's values giving and sum them, but with different "weight". *100 to the first, *10 to the second, and *1 to the third:

```
=MAP(B2:B5, C2:C5, D2:D5, LAMBDA(a,b,c,RANK(a,B2:B5)*100+RANK(b,C2:C5)*10+RANK(c,D2:D5)*1))
```

That returns something like this:

[image]

Then wrapped it in LAMBDA in order to be used as the new source of RANKING, and calculated it with the help of BYROW. But now the ranking needs to be done in reversed order. The greater values are going to equal to the ones at the bottomo of the ranking and vice versa. That's why the 0 in `RANK(e,r,0)` :

```
=LAMBDA(r,BYROW(r,LAMBDA(e,RANK(e,r,0))))(MAP(B2:B5, C2:C5, D2:D5, LAMBDA(a,b,c,RANK(a,B2:B5)*100+RANK(b,C2:C5)*10+RANK(c,D2:D5)*1)))
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Let me know!

**NOTE:** This would work great until 9 players, if you or anyone else needs it for more, you should change 100,10,1 with the amount of players + 1 elevated to the "priority" of the category. The first one the highest. For example, for 15 players, I would multiply the first ranking by: 16^3,16^2 and 16^1. For 20 players and 4 categories: 21^4,21^3,21^2,21^1 - Hope it's clear for universalization!

Comment: PS: as a tip if it helps: to adapt the ranges for Session 2, I copied the formula from B14 in B20, and then cut it and pasted it back in C14. It may be helpful if you have to repeat it over